# ASP.NET session crashing only on 1 client's IE 11

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, internet-explorer-11

I have recently modified a code behind class in an asp.net application to store object in sessions. This pages throws a "null object" exception when trying to access the sessions but only for a particular user and only for IE 11. Any other browser works everywhere.

We have tried to delete IE sessions cookies on that browser for that PC but this does not help.
Does someone have any better suggestion?

many thanks in advance

Comment: Does (s)he have cookies disabled?

Comment: Good question. Let me phone the user and get back. And where can he see that cookies are disabled?

Comment: The users browser accept cookies. Indeed the cookies settings match mine where this problem does not occur

Comment: I would also suggest to test it on IE 11 on another machine and make sure you can replicate the error.

Comment: This is the problem. It works everywhere else on IE 11. I have tested on dozens of machines now.

Comment: Does the user have the same problem on another machine with IE 11 and IE != 11 ?

Comment: This works for every other browser on the machine of the user with the problem. User only have IE11 installed. Chrome works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking system time on that PC. Maybe the IE is treating the cookie as expired

Comment: Just to make sure i understand, are you suggesting that the system time is out your sync with the "correct" time?

Comment: Yes, it might be the case. It could result into session cookie being already expired each time you assign it.

Comment: But the user can log in to the site. Doesn't that exclude this case? Log in also do store session cookies on the client machine?

Comment: My idea was that the auth and session cookies have a diferrent timeout. But since the time is correct the expiration isn't an issue